# Getting from a model to the model type's verbose name

Tags: django, django-models

I've got an instance of a model `FooBar` - how do I get the naturalised type `Foo Bar` for display to the user, making sure to use the class's `verbose_name` if one is set in the `Meta` options. e.g.:

```
class FooBar(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

  class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Spaghetti Monster'
```

How do I get 'Spaghetti Monster' from an instance of a `FooBar`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`foobar._meta.verbose_name`

Comment: Won't that only work if the class has a `Meta` subclass? (See the first part of the question too).

Comment: Models always have a `Meta` inner class, even if it's one generated implicitly by Django. And that class always has a `verbose_name` attribute. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#verbose-name